# ListView isn't working, it is not displaying the listView on the main page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview, android-adapter

my ListView isn't working, it is not displaying the listView on the main page. Any solutions?

Does it have to do with my layout file too? I will attach the layout file below too!

I was trying to make an adapter for the listview

It is just a simple one page application which I try to learn how to use listview. Did I do any wrong about the code? I was mainly following a youtube tutorial for this but still an error occur

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ListView myListView;
    String [] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);

        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items);
        myListView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

      //  myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.));

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ItemAdapter.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

//A class that are BaseAdapter but with another name call 'ItemAdapter'

//To pass values/data to ListView

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String[] items;

    public ItemAdapter(Context c, String[] i){
        items = i;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     //To initialize inflater
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_details,null);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        String name = items[i];

        nameTextView.setText(name);

        return v;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="Your Library"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/round_add_white_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my_listview_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: try change `listView` width and height to `match_parent` and see.

Comment: It work! Can you explain why?

Comment: `match_parent` will make the width and height match to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this
Change Height and width 0dp to as below

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: Changing to match parent works! Can you explain why?

Comment: bacause when you take width 0dp  static  than now show listview  actual data load but display not content because of  odp witdh @Ng Jing Xuan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ItemAdapter a custom class. If you have very simple list then just use the built-in ArrayAdapter class to register the listview.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);  
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
```

-- > Try to check items.length in toast or console. Check if it is showing data or not.